# Change navigation options

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am making mobile app. I have 3 pages that are on tab navigation. 1st page is page with articles, second is with courses. I have made navigation from 1st page to second. But there was a problem with navigation options (with title). When i navigate to second page from first i have 2 titles. But i want to make 1:[image]

You can that there is 2 titles, first is < and second is "Courses", i want to make it like this "< Courses". Help me please. Code:

```html
// 1st page

import Courses from './Courses'

<Button
onPress={() => {
   navigate('Courses')
}}
 title="More courses"
/>

  const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
      },
      Courses: {
        screen: Courses,
      },
      Details: {
        screen: DetailsScreen,
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
    }
  );

  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

  export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <AppContainer />;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you have two stack navigators

Comment: @Junius L i have already done, this did not help me